# How to perform Wiresharks File->Extract Objects->HTTP through Tshark commandline interface?

Tags: http, wireshark, packet-capture, tshark, sniffing

Using TShark, I want to be able to extract the payload in HTTP response from packets data captured through tshark in a .pcap file.

In the Wireshark GUI, I was able to do that by `File > Extract Objects > HTTP`, and then choosing a file from the HTTP Objects dialog (which shows a list of all HTTP objects), and saving it on my disk. This process is described [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html#ChIOExportObjectsDialog).

The question is that how can I do it in Tshark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if TShark can do it, but you can use [Chaosreader](http://www.brendangregg.com/chaosreader.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you. I got the HTTP payload, but I also want source and destination IPs as well as port numbers. Can you guide me a bit about how to get those. I posted a question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/799570/in-the-output-of-chaosreader-where-are-the-source-and-destination-port-numbers).