# In the output of Chaosreader, where are the source and destination port numbers and IP addresses for each packet?

Tags: tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffer, packet-analyzer, sniffing

I used [this tutorial](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/windows_networking/Studying-Network-Activity-Using-Chaosreader-Tool.html) to use `Chaosreader` on an output file of `WinDump`. My purpose was to get the `HTTP` payload, which I got. But I'd also like to extract other information, like **`source IP`** and **`destination IP`**, **`source port`** and **`destination port`**, for each packet in the `WinDump` output file.

How do I get those fields? Where are they in the output files generated by `chaosreader`?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of reading the file(s)? That should be a standard thing for a packet capture program to record. Have you considered Wireshark? It should show you that info. https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Yes, but I need a commandline tool which i can automate in a program, and Tshark does not offer export of objects like Wireshark does, and like I mentioned, my primary purpose was to extract HTTP payload.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Do you think it's a good reason to downvote my question - that you don't agree with my choice of the tool or that I couldn't find what I exactly need in the files generated by the tool I am using?

Comment: I have no problem with your question and I didn't down vote it. I was trying to help you. It was some other anonymous person... pesky buggers.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Oh, my bad! I am so sorry!